# Why JSON.parse fails with this array-like string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I tried to JSON parse this

```
  let string = `["\"test1, "\"test2"]`;
  let array = JSON.parse(string);
  console.log(array[0]);
```

It's fairly simple enough but I don't understand what's error message is supposed to tell

```
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 3
```

Comment: You need to escape your backslash, if you want it in the string, and you have one extra quote, which isn't escaped at all.

Comment: `[""test1, ""test2"]` is not valid JSON.  Is this just a question about a typo and it should be closed as such?  Or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using template string to create a string.
it doesnt need a escape character for double quotes ".
type this:

```
let string = `["test1", "test2"]`;
let array = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(array[0])
```

you need a escape character for " only when you are using normal string. like this:

```
let string = "[\"test1\", \"test2\"]";
let array = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(array[0])
```

im not good at english.hope useful